# XML multiple nodes into dataGridView with 2 column

Tags: c#, xml, datagridview

I'm trying to put this xml into a `DataGridView` with the data grid view **only** showing the *nodes* and the *value*.

I have tried using `switch`, `case`, `foreach` node yet the result the node and value only showing on 1 column instead 2 column. I'm tried using select single node, but it showing object error.,

Here's an example of the code:

```
try
            {
                reader = new XmlTextReader(filename);
                reader.WhitespaceHandling = WhitespaceHandling.None;
               

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    

                    switch (reader.NodeType)
                    {
                        case XmlNodeType.Element:
                            //dataGridView1.Rows[cnt].Cells[1].Value = reader.Name;
                            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(reader.Name);
                            break;
                        case XmlNodeType.Text:
                            dataGridView1.Rows.Add("\t",reader.Value);
                            //dataGridView1.Rows[cnt].Cells[0].Value = reader.Value;
                            break;
                        case XmlNodeType.EndElement:
                            break;
                    }
```

my Mentor said, use this code but i dont know what's missing with my mentor example

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.Load("ConfigAPI.xml");

            XmlNodeList nodeList = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/ConfigAPI");
            
               foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
            {
            node.SelectSingleNode("UIPlayer").InnerText;
            }
```

also here's an example of the XML

```
<ConfigAPI>
  <CoreUIAddress>http://localhost:3223</CoreUIAddress>
  <CoreAppsAddress>http://localhost:3333</CoreAppsAddress>
  <CoreCustomPrinterAddress>http://localhost:3001</CoreCustomPrinterAddress>
  <CorePassbookPrinterAddress>http://localhost:3002</CorePassbookPrinterAddress>
  <CorePrinterAddress>http://localhost:3003</CorePrinterAddress>
  <CoreEDCAddress>http://localhost:3010</CoreEDCAddress>
  <CoreCamAddress>http://localhost:3011</CoreCamAddress>
  <CoreUPSAddress>http://localhost:3012</CoreUPSAddress>
</ConfigAPI>
```

by using the first code, it shown something like this (without "\t")

```
Column 1                       Column 2
core UI Adress
http localhost
core APps
http localhost
```

not sure how to shown the data on 2nd Column so it can be view like this

```
Column 1                      Column 2
Core Ui Adress                 Http Localhost
Core APPs                      Http Localhost
```

Comment: What's the error you are getting?  Can you place that into your question by editing it.  I have also tidied up your question a bit, hope you don't mind.  +1 regardless.  Good luck!

Comment: hello @MickyD, when i do the first code, it shown no error, it shown something like this in the data grid view. (Without the "\t")
Column 1                  Column2
CoreUI
http:localhost
Core apps 
http localhost

what im trying to do to make the value on 2nd column..   by using the"\t", it shown on 2n column, but constantly skipped by empty cells..

Comment: What are you wanting in the grid? Column 1 would be? Column 2 would be? It looks like there are eight elements in the ConfigAPI node. In addition, “\t” is NOT going to go to the next cell in the grid.

Comment: Hello @JohnG, yes i understand there are 8 different element, my mentor shown its possible so that element will shown like my last statement, by using my mentor way, its shown this "error Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression StateOnly assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement XMLtoDataTable".

Comment: Well… the second snippet of code looks like the correct approach. You need to change the code such that… the line of code… `node.SelectSingleNode("UIPlayer").InnerText;` … is going to “RETURN” a value. The current code is not getting this “returned” value. It should be something like… `var coreUIAddress = node.SelectSingleNode("CoreUIAddress").InnerText;` …

Comment: NOTE how “UIPlayer” is changed to the “field name” you want from the XML. Using the test data shown, the loop will only execute once. So, It is unclear if the posted XML is complete or just a portion, such that there are multiple ConfigAPI nodes.

Comment: Also, as I mentioned earlier, it is unclear how the XML would translate to 2 columns… I would think it would be eight columns?

Comment: Hello @JohnG, by using the method that i knew, it became 8 collumn, that's why i confuse, how my mentor make it into 2 columns only, which column 1 gonna be node, and the column 2 gonna be the value...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the few lines of code in the second example posted and the given XML… Below should display the data is two columns.

```
  XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
  xmlDoc.Load(@"PathToYourXMLFile\ConfigAPI.xml");
  XmlNodeList RootNodeList = xmlDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/ConfigAPI");
  for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    dataGridView1.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn());
  }
  foreach (XmlNode ConfigNode in RootNodeList[0]) {
    foreach (XmlNode childNode in ConfigNode.ChildNodes) {
      int newRowIndex = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
      dataGridView1.Rows[newRowIndex].Cells[0].Value = childNode.ParentNode.Name;
      dataGridView1.Rows[newRowIndex].Cells[1].Value = childNode.InnerText;
    }
  }
```

Addition per OP comment...

It is a little confusing in a sense that the first “outer” loop isn’t really necessary using the posted XML. When I tested the code, I had numerous `ConfigAPI` nodes in the XML file. Not just the one as you have posted. So, you could simplify this to one loop with…

```
foreach (XmlNode childNode in RootNodeList[0].ChildNodes) {
  int newRowIndex = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
  dataGridView1.Rows[newRowIndex].Cells[0].Value = childNode.Name;
  dataGridView1.Rows[newRowIndex].Cells[1].Value = childNode.InnerText;
}
```

Comment: Hello Mr.John, thank you for your answer, i have troubled understanding with that nested foreach logic ?